# wait exits after trap

Tags: bash, signals

I need to handle SIGTERM and keep script running.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo do-nothing' SIGTERM
sleep 10m &
wait $!
```

Why after SIGTERM script exits and how to make it run until `sleep 10m &` is  finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals cause `wait` to exit with a status equal to the signal number plus 128. To get the real exit status, loop until `$?` is less.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo trapped' INT TERM
sleep 10 & pid=$!

while wait $pid; test $? -ge 128
do echo 'finished wait'
done

echo bye
```

Note that `test` overwrites `$?` with its own exit status, so if you care about the real exit status from `wait`, you'll have to create a variable between `wait` and `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo SIGTERM' SIGTERM
sleep 1m &
echo waiting
wait $!
echo Got signal but still waiting
wait $!
echo bye
```

output:

```
waiting
SIGTERM
Got signal but still waiting
bye
```

It will "swallow" **one** SIGTERM signal and exit after `sleep 1m &` is finished.

Comment: What if you receive two?

Answer (score 0):

The signal will always transfer the execution point away from the `wait` to the `trap`, and apparently will pick up at the next statement, having broken the `wait`.

Maybe this?

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo nope; wait $pid' term
sleep 10m & pid=$1
wait $pid
echo "Done - exited with code '$?'"
date
```